# Is there a machine learning model in Python for prediction of the next set of "random" numbers in a sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have a dataset with three columns, each has a number 0-9. There are ~6700 rows in the set. I am wondering if it is possible to create a machine learning model to predict the next set of three numbers (one in each column)? If this is possible, how difficult is it and what type of a model would you recommend?

I am newer to machine learning so any help would be great!

Thank you!

I have tried using different kinds of LSTMs using tensorflow, but the results appeared to be averages rather than predictions.

Here is one of the attempts I made:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Numbers1.xlsx', sheet_name='midday training')
dataset_train = df.iloc[:, 1:]
dataset_train = dataset_train.iloc[::-1]
time_series_data = np.array(df)
training_set = time_series_data[:, 1:4]


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

x_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(1, 6003):
    x_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-1:i, :3])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, :3])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (6002,1,3))
                     
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 3)))
regressor.add(Dropout(.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 3))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size = 32)

dataset_test = pd.read_excel('Numbers1.xlsx', sheet_name='midday')
dataset_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:]
dataset_test = dataset_test.iloc[::-1]
real = dataset_test

dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train, dataset_test), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 1:].values
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
x_test = []

for i in range(1, 6734):
    x_test.append(inputs[i-1:i, :3])
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (6733,1,3))
predicted = regressor.predict(x_test)
predicted = sc.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

Comment: Hi @NumberLover, I need some more details on the dataset to understand the issue. What is the output of `df.head()`? Also, Does this dataset contain sequential data to use LSTM? Please check this link for [Models with multiple inputs and outputs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs) as a refrence reference if you are looking for multiple outputs.